# Combining a variable value and string to form another variable

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I want to reference a bash variable from a variable without using:

```
echo "${!VARNAME}"
```

Any ideas? Since I want to use the variable on fly and many such references are there, I can't declare them to another variable and use it.

Example:

```
var1=host
${var1}_file ----> host_file is another variable that i want to call in a command.
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this in the end? What kind of data do you have there? I'm sort of wondering if there wouldn't be a better way to do this.

Comment: What is the reason not to use  "${!VARNAME}" ?

Comment: What we generally do is add concatenated variable and string to a variable and use that variable in "${!VARNAME}" . But i do not want to pass concatenated value to another variable but use it directly. something like ` ls host_file`. Like this i have to use multiple variables in a single command.

Comment: @RajeshReddyB, yes, you explained in the question you want to generate variable names on the fly. I was trying to ask _why_. This has the smell of asking for X when you're actually trying to do Y. (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [here](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: I'm actually trying to run execute below command.                                             hadoop jar $DistcpJar -libjars $DistcpAclLibJar -Ddfs.encryption.key.provider.uri=${DestCluster}_${KmsUrl} -sourceconf $SourceConf -pugb -skipcrccheck -update hdfs://$(${SourceCluster}_NameService):${SourceCluster}_NameServicePort/$Source hdfs://${DestCluster}_NameService:${DestCluster}_NameServicePort/$DestLocation ------------------- where Source cluster is a positional parameter i pass to the main script and combining with another name forms a different variable.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really see why you would not want to use variable indirection unless you are writing a `sh` (not `bash`) script.

As has been mentioned, `eval` will work, but is generally frowned upon as its use has the potential to be dangerous, especially when evaluating user-supplied data without careful sanitation.

Another way of achieving the same effect is to use name-reference variables (available in `bash` since version 4.3).

```
var1=host

declare -n nameref="${var1}_file"

nameref="something something"

printf '%s\n' "$host_file"
```

This would output the string `something something`. Using `typeset -n` in place of `declare -n` would make it work in both `bash` and in `ksh93`.

Comment: I have actually tried this but declare doesn't have -n option and couldn't go further.

Comment: @RajeshReddyB This indicates that your `bash` is older than release 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you have variables named as a combination of some proper name, and related attributes you should probably use associative arrays instead. Assuming you have Bash 4.x, ksh or zsh, that is. See a [page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) or [another](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays) on BashGuide.
(Actually structures like in C would be nice, but you can't really get that with Bash.)

That is, to store a URL and a port for the hosts/clusters `oregon` and `arizona`, don't make four variables `arizona_url`, `arizona_port`, `oregon_url`, `oregon_port`, but instead something like this:

```
typeset -A urls ports
urls[oregon]="http://..."
urls[arizona]="http://..."
ports[oregon]=1234
ports[arizona]=2345
```

and then use those with `"${urls[$hostname1]}"`, `"${ports[$hostname]}"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As per the previous answer, you can use eval for this.

> eval [arg ...]
>                 The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single com‐
>                 mand.  This command is then read and executed by the shell,  and
>                 its  exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are
>                 no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0. (from bash man page)

However, this is one of those bad programming habits that you need to be very aware of and use as little as possible. It can normally be avoided for something more elegant, less error-prone and easier to debug.

```
var1=host
eval echo ${var1}_file # print contents of $host_file
```

Comment: `${!var1}` is as dangerous as `eval` if the content of `$var1` may be under the control of an attacker. That code is not correct, it should have been `eval 'echo "${'"$var1"'_file}"'`

Answer (score 0):

**It works with arrays too!**

Below is a generalization of @Kusalananda 's approach, but with arrays...

```
declare -a array_a=()
declare -n array_b="array_a"
for ((i=0;i<=9;i++)); do
    array_b+=($i)
done
length=${#array_a[*]}
for ((i=0;i<=$(($length-1));i++)); do
    echo "${array_a[$i]}"
done
```

**Thanks!**